# Keynote and Recorded Presentations

Tags: audio, keynote, recording

If you "Record Slideshow" in Keynote then it'll listen to your computer's microphone and make well-sync'd presentation you can save to .mov and share, but it's pretty damned big, even for a short presentation.

Is there any way to export *only* the audio and the slide timing info from Keynote once your recording has been made?

The options I can see are iPod, HTML, Images, PDF, PPT and Quicktime. With a bit of faff I can extract the audio from the Quicktime, but I'll have lost the timing info.

Ideally I'd be able to export "Images with Timing info" which would give me the images and a file of timestamps linked to filenames which I could use to pair the two up.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: To take this one step further, what are you going to do with this "images and timeline" data that will need to be stored in some format? (I'm not aware of a good standard format for that, but that's a tertiary problem at this point). It seems Apple is solving this problem for you by making iWork a web app that runs in all modern browsers on Linux, Windows and OS X/iOS - so that you'll skip the intermediary step of making a movie in the first place before too long.

Comment: I'd like to be able to build a custom HTML5 app to play the audio that was recorded, and change the image being displayed in accordance with the exported timing track. Ultimate the format is irrelevant to me, so long as I can grab the images (which I can do) the audio (which I can extract from the movie) and the timings (which I can't get atm)

Comment: Excellent - Apple will tip it's hands on how it constructs an HTML5 app from arbitrary Keynote presentations this fall. If you want to kick the tires now, you can sign up as a developer to test iWork in the cloud today. Note, we don't consider beta questions on-topic here, so the details of this will have to wait until Apple releases this to the general public.

Comment: Great - thanks! But to confirm, there is no way of extracting the slide timings from Keynote '09 (in any format) so I can code the conversion and HTML5 app myself today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since keynote files are just zip archives with XML documents and assets stored in a fairly obvious folder structure, I'd start with moving your Keynote into a folder with nothing else and use the terminal `unzip` command to extract everything.

The `index.apxl` file will have your timing information stored in plain text and encoded as XML - so you might be able to parse that with an XML tool or otherwise extract your timing.

I don't think the file is documented publicly other than the various public namespace declarations in the header of the file, but it's a start to cracking your timeline problem *if you don't mind spelunking in XML and reverse engineering the commands recorded within the file*.

Comment: *awesome*. Great advice.